# Flash Media Playback with param "controlBarMode = none" doesn't pause?

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming

I am testing [Flash Media Playback](http://www.osmf.org/configurator/fmp/), and I want a player with only an overlay play button on the center, with the param controlBarMode = none it looks good, but once you click play, there's no way to pause the video.

Is there a way to show an overlay pause button on the center onMouseOver?

Answer (score -1):

replace "none" with "yes"

done! easy as pie!

Comment: I think this would be better as a comment.